# facebook auto post

Tags: facebook

I want to develop a facebook application that make auto post to a facebook page

like this one http://apps.facebook.com/twitter/ but my application get post from other site

when user make a post in my site it will send to the facebook page even this user not loged in facebook or not page admin .

tnx  for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You'll need to do an initial login to facebook through a webservice and request elevated rights (publish_stream and offline_access), and then save the authentication token that comes back.  You can then reuse this token and post to a facebook wall without anyone having to explicitly login to facebook.

I did this using Hammock to create the webservice calls to facebook.